# Consequences of recycling Bitmaps?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, frame-rate

Hi in my application I have an explosion animation that comes up extremely often. when creating an explosion I load 3 images from resources then once the explosion animation is over I recycle those 3 images. I am constantly doing this and have noticed framerate drops. Is their a better way of doing this like static bitmaps or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once made an application, a simple canvas on which bombs exploded.
I used a tiled bitmap composed of each step of the explosion and drew only a part of it, which changes often in order to create the animation effect.
It updates steps automatically following currentTimestamp

So this is the explosion class:

```
public class ExplosionAnimated {

private static final String TAG = ExplosionAnimated.class.getSimpleName();

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Rect mSourceRect;
private int mFrameCountX;
private int mFrameCountY;
private int mCurrentFrame;
private long mFrameTicker;
private int mFramePeriod;

private int mSpriteWidth;
private int mSpriteHeight;

private int mX;
private int mY;

private boolean mFinished = false;

public ExplosionAnimated(Bitmap pBitmap, int pX, int pY, 
        int pFrameCountX, int pFrameCountY, int pFps) {

    this.mBitmap = pBitmap;
    this.mX = pX;
    this.mY = pY;
    this.mCurrentFrame = 0;
    this.mFrameCountX = pFrameCountX;
    this.mFrameCountY = pFrameCountY;
    this.mSpriteWidth = pBitmap.getWidth() / pFrameCountX;
    this.mSpriteHeight = pBitmap.getHeight() / pFrameCountY;
    this.mSourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, this.mSpriteWidth, this.mSpriteHeight);
    this.mFramePeriod = 1000 / pFps;
    this.mFrameTicker = 0l;
}

public void update(long gameTime) {

    if (gameTime > this.mFrameTicker + this.mFramePeriod) {
        this.mFrameTicker = gameTime;

        this.mCurrentFrame++;
        if (this.mCurrentFrame >= this.mFramePeriod) {
            this.mCurrentFrame = 0;
            this.mFinished = true;
        }
    }

    if (!this.mFinished) {

        this.mSourceRect.left = this.mCurrentFrame * this.mSpriteWidth;
        this.mSourceRect.right = this.mSourceRect.left + this.mSpriteWidth;
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    Rect destRect = new Rect(this.mX, this.mY, 
            this.mX + this.mSpriteWidth, 
            this.mY + this.mSpriteHeight);
    canvas.drawBitmap(this.mBitmap, this.mSourceRect, destRect, null);
}

public boolean isFinished() {
    return this.mFinished;
}
}
```

These are methods from an object (Bomb.java for exemple) that starts explosion and draw it:

```
public void explode(Context pContext, Canvas pCanvas) {

    this.mState = State.EXPLODING;
    this.mExplosion = new ExplosionAnimated(this.mExplosionBitmap, 
            (int) this.mX, (int) this.mY, 7, 3, 7);
}

public void doDraw(Canvas pCanvas) {

    if (this.mState == State.EXPLODING) {

        if (this.mExplosion.isFinished()) {
            this.mState = State.EXPLODED;
        } else {
            this.mExplosion.update(System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.mExplosion.draw(pCanvas);
        }
    } else {
        pCanvas.drawBitmap(this.mBombBitmap, this.mX, this.mY, null);
    } 
}
```

I used a Thread and a SurfaceView to continually draw the bomb (or the explosion), giving just the currentTimestamp to update the explosion.

I hope it helps, and if you need I can show and explain more code

Comment: thanks for the code helps alot. So instead of loading the bitmap inside your explosion class you load in in your surfaceview class then pass it in so it only has to be loaded once. Got it thanks!